# C program compilation error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am new to programming and picked up the C language as my first computer language. I was doing a sample conversion program and when i compiled the code, i get the following error.

What does it mean and how do i fix it?

Thanks!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConversionProgram, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 24-07-2012 20:58:37.

1>InitializeBuildStatus:

1> Touching "Debug\ExcerciseProgram1.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1> conversion.cpp
1>c:\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\excerciseprogram1\excerciseprogram1\question2.cpp(12): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(304) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>c:\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\excerciseprogram1\excerciseprogram1\question2.cpp(18): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\excerciseprogram1\excerciseprogram1\question2.cpp(32): error C2857: '#include' statement specified with the /YcStdAfx.h command-line option was not found in the source file
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.1
```

I am using VB 2010 as my IDE

Comment: You have errors on lines 12, 18, 32 of your `question2.cpp` file (a C++ source file, not a C one!). Without that file, we cannot help you more.

Comment: I believe that you should not choose *C* (or *C++*) as your *first* programming language. Choosing *Ocaml*, *Scheme*, *Python* or *Common Lisp* would learn you more. Once you learn to program a little bit in a high-level language, learning *C* is less hard.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch A small correction: compiler outputs for lines 12, 18 are warnings not errors. Neverheless they need to be corrected before they result to an error ;)

Comment: A beginner should handle warnings as errors; even an expert should ordinarily do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you are experiencing a compile error is mentioned here:

> error C2857: '#include' statement specified with the /YcStdAfx.h command-line option was not found in the source

This means that the compiler is making the inclusion of `StdAfx.h` compulsory. You can remedy this by adding `#include <StdAfx.h>` to your source code.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your source file is not including the precompiled header file. All source files must, as first non-comment, include `"stdafx.h"` if you are using precompiled headers.